# From where Airflow pull env variable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow

I'm seeing some dags and where I'm seeing `os.getenv("AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID")`, but I'm not able to see where it is being set.

Is it a default variable which airflow produces at run time ?

Using `Airflow 2.5.2` version

Can anyone share where I can see the set part of this variable ? And doc ref of Airflow will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a default variable which airflow produces at run time ?

Yes it happens as part of getting the task ready for execution.

If you are asking where is the code that makes it happen the answer can be found on [these lines of the source code here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/827962878e6fb39e014639d83cff7d0881595ecb/airflow/utils/operator_helpers.py#L29-L35)

If you are asking about how it happens then we need to walk through Airflow code base. For the sake of simplicity I will not explain the whole process but only the relevant parts to the question.

One of the steps of preparing your task for execution is invoking [_execute_task_with_callbacks](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f60d458dc08a5d5fbe5903fffca8f7b03009f49a/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L2435). This function among other things invokes this [code block](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f60d458dc08a5d5fbe5903fffca8f7b03009f49a/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L2473-L2475):

```
        # Export context to make it available for operators to use.
        airflow_context_vars = context_to_airflow_vars(context, in_env_var_format=True)
        os.environ.update(airflow_context_vars)
```

Note that the last step of this code block is to update the env variables.
Now to understand how this happens we need to review the function `context_to_airflow_vars`. It basically creates the needed dict to update the env vars. Note to the mapping that happens on this [line](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/827962878e6fb39e014639d83cff7d0881595ecb/airflow/utils/operator_helpers.py#L114) which links to the code lines I shared at the beginning of the answer (see [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/827962878e6fb39e014639d83cff7d0881595ecb/airflow/utils/operator_helpers.py#L28-L35) again):

```
DEFAULT_FORMAT_PREFIX = "airflow.ctx."
ENV_VAR_FORMAT_PREFIX = "AIRFLOW_CTX_"

AIRFLOW_VAR_NAME_FORMAT_MAPPING = {
    "AIRFLOW_CONTEXT_DAG_ID": {
        "default": f"{DEFAULT_FORMAT_PREFIX}dag_id",
        "env_var_format": f"{ENV_VAR_FORMAT_PREFIX}DAG_ID",
    },
```